# How to measure difference between RGB colors taking into account human perception

Tags: algorithm, colors, rgb, similarity

How to measure difference between RGB colors taking into account human perception, the goal is to build distance function which will tell that red and green are totally different, and light green and green are pretty similar, co distance should measure hue/shade between similar colours if the colors are the same.

---

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [CIE DeltaE 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIEDE2000) or colour differences in perceptually-uniform colourspaces such as [CAM16-UCS](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/col.22131) or [JzAzBz](https://www.osapublishing.org/viewmedia.cfm?uri=oe-25-13-15131) where applying simple Euclidean distance is fine within reason.

We have implementations of all of them in [colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour) if you need numerical references. Importantly though, most of the metrics are valid for small colour differences, usually less than 10 CIE L*a*b* units, for large colour differences, you would probably need something like [HyAB](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/col.22451).